# Windows10 script pin app to start menu

Tags: powershell, win-universal-app, windows-10, startmenu, comobject

I have a Universal App that I'm sideloading in Windows10.  I would like to create a script (Powershell, VBS, batch, etc) to pin it to the Start Menu.

I have found many examples of how to write a script that pins a desktop application (like this one: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-pin-items-to-51be533c ).  I've tried using the script to pin the actual App .exe file located in C:\Program Files\WindowsApps... but that doesn't work.  When I try and pin that way, I run DoIt(), which doesn't return anything.  There are no error messages, but the tile is not pinned to the start menu.

My guess is that instead of using a ComObject to interact with the file system I need a ComObject that interacts with some sort of App manager.  I'm not sure how to get a list of available ComObjects to tell if this is even a possibility.

Comment: Appears to be a known issue with Windows 10: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1609288/pin-to-taskbar-no-longer-working-in-windows-10

Comment: It might be related, although the issue the link is complaining about is that the verb is not present.  The pin to start verb is present for me.  Although I did try pinning a desktop application to the start menu and that didn't work.