# Where are windows Verb integer references defined?

Tags: windows, shell-verbs

I have found a number of sites (like [this](http://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=566)) that use code like this

```
$verbs = @{  
 "PintoStartMenu"=5381 
   "UnpinfromStartMenu"=5382 
   "PintoTaskbar"=5386 
   "UnpinfromTaskbar"=5387 
}
```

to allow for working with verbs language agnostically. However, I am now trying to combine that with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791289/pin-program-to-start-menu-using-ps-in-windows-10) to allow for working with Start in Windows 10. But, I need to find the integer for Pin to Start, vs Pin to Start Menu. And for the life of me I can't find where those integers are defined.

Comment: I guess a further question then is, how SHOULD one handle things like Pin to Taskbar across multiple languages, when the verbs are changing? Does MS just ship different versions of shell32.dll.mui and address this stuff on the fly themselves?

Comment: Funny, everyone says that, but MY customers are IT & BIM Managers who want to do exactly this, and for very good, user SUPPORTIVE reasons. I agree software vendors should't, but the idea that Microsoft says internal IT can't? Lame.