# appresolver.dll or similar in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, powershell

I am trying to simplify my approach to pinning apps, and I have found something with potential that uses

```
$shell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
$nameSpace = $shell.NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}')
```

This produces a list of programs, which I can then look for available Verbs on. Woot. In Windows 10. The GUID doesn't exist in Windows 7.
I dug up the GUID (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}`) and the default value of the `InProcServer32` key is `C:\Windows\System32\appresolver.dll`. That makes sense, I need to resolve available apps.
So, I did some searching and appresolver.dll is a Windows 10 thing. So, is there a mechanism to list all available programs in Windows 10 also?

My ultimate goal is to expand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791289/pin-program-to-start-menu-using-ps-in-windows-10) solution to support all verbs but Pin to Taskbar in Windows 10 (which is a special case) and also use the `[CosmosKey.Util.MuiHelper]` type to resolve language localized Verb strings. But until I can get a list of program objects that contains a Verbs() collection I am at a loss.